# ssh connection refused; ssh: connect to host [address] port 22: Connection refused

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, openssh, nvidia-jetson

I have one TP link wifi connector USB on ARM device. And I am sharing my laptop's hotspot and connecting with it. Its connecting fine. But when I try to connect **same** TP link to another ARM device, and when I try to do ssh, it says connection refused!!

Any idea why is this happening ?

I have tried few solutions on my own to solve this.

1. deleting the address from known_hosts in C > USER > .ssh > known_hosts
2. trying installing 'sudo apt-get install openssh-server' on the new ARM again.

SO it works, But I have only 1 TP link, and I  have to do this everytime I change the ARM device.

any easy solution for this ? and explanation on why is this happening ?